# insert data into table from a dataset

Tags: c#, sql

I  have a dataset with 18000 + rows in it. Is there a way to insert it in to the SQL server database table with out going through dataset row by row? The dataset will
have exactly the same structure as database table. I have more then 4 columns 
columns that i get. Any code samples or links would be great. Thank you all
very much

Answer (score 3):

You can use [SQLBulkCopy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/30c3y597.aspx) with the method: 
[SqlBulkCopy.WriteToServer Method (DataTable) - MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ex21zs8x.aspx)

> Copies all rows in the supplied DataTable to a destination table
>   specified by the DestinationTableName property of the SqlBulkCopy
>   object.

Something like:

```
using (SqlBulkCopy bulkCopy = new SqlBulkCopy(connection))
            {
                bulkCopy.DestinationTableName = 
                    "dbo.BulkCopyDemoMatchingColumns";

                try
                {
                    // Write from the source to the destination.
                    // Check if the data set is not null and tables count > 0 etc
                    bulkCopy.WriteToServer(yourDataSet.Tables[0]);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

Use sqlbulkcopy component of C#.net. Please check the details with examples [**HERE**](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18418/Transferring-Data-Using-SqlBulkCopy)